# Do I give cross_val_score() the entire dataset or just the training-set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

As the documentation of the class is not very clear. I don't understand what value I give it.

> cross_val_score(estimator, X, y=None)

This is my code:

```
clf = LinearSVC(random_state=seed, **params)
cvscore = cross_val_score(clf, features, labels)
```

I am not sure if this is correct or if I need to give X_train and y_train instead of features and labels.

Thanks

Answer (score 9):

It is always a good idea to separate the test set and training set, even while using cross_val_score. The reason behind this is knowledge leaking. It basically means that when you use both training and test sets, you are leaking information from test set into your model, thereby making your model biased, leading to incorrect predictions.

Here is detailed [blog post](http://www.alfredo.motta.name/cross-validation-done-wrong/) on the same issue.

References:

- [Reddit post on cross-validation](https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/2xagx4/when_crossvalidation_goes_wrong_model_inspection/)
- [Cross_val_Score example showing correct way of using it](http://queirozf.com/entries/scikit-learn-pipeline-examples)
- [A similar question on stats.stackexchange](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/239023/when-using-cross-validation-shouldnt-it-be-mandatory-to-pipeline-the-preproces)

Comment: But if I exclusively use the cross_val_score to comparehyperparameters, then the leaking would not be an issue, right?

Comment: It will be issue,  because again the hyperparameters will be incorrectly tuned since you will be using the combined dataset. The main point here is that you should leave some data out separate to validate/test your model.

Comment: Okay this is confusing, basically you and azurekirby say the opposite...

Comment: @ToTom - Apologies. I should make things clearer. As I have discussed earlier - We need a test and train set. This is so that you can test the models performance against a hold out set. The only case you do not have a test-train set is when you 100% are confident that you are happy with the model you have chosen (i.e. the score meets your thres-hold). What Mohammed is aluding towards is the prior. If you aren't happy with your model performance, you should have a test-train split. Otherwise if you are, you can pass in the full data set.

Answer (score 5):

I assume you were referring to the below documentation:
[sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_score.html)

The purpose of cross validation is ensuring that your model hasn't had particularly high variance leading to a good-fit in one instance, but a poor fit in another instance. This is used generally in model **validation**. With this in mind, you should be passing the training set (X_train, y_train) and seeing how your model performs.

Your question was focused on:
"Can I pass in the **whole** data-set into cross validation?"

The answer is, yes. This is conditional and based off whether or not you are satisfied with your ML output. Say for example, I have the following below:
[image: ROC Curve]
I have used a Random forest model and am happy with my overall model fit and score.

In this case, I have a hold-out set.
Once I remove this hold-out set and give my model the **whole** data-set, we would get a plot with an even higher score as I am giving my model more information (and as such, your CV scores will also reflectively be higher).

An example of calling the method might be as such:
**probablistic_scores = cross_val_score(model, X_train, y_train, cv=5)**

Generally a 5 Fold Cross validation is preferred.
If you wish to go higher than 5 fold - please note that as your 'n' folds increase, the number of computational resources required will also increase and will take longer to process.

Comment: Thank you, but are you sure?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html 

Here they make examples with the entire dataset, not just the X_train...

Comment: @ToTom  - This is dependent on your situation. If and only If you have 100% confirmed the model you wish to use and wish to improve your Area-Under-Curve (AUC) and fit score further, then you would pass the entire data set. Generally, when we still want to have a hold-out set to test the model against in the future, we don't do this. I would recommend you also taking a look at 'Leave One Out Cross Validation' if you are interested in this further.

Comment: Basically the task is to compare the hyperparameters for LinearSVC. Meaning the model is confirmed and I am just looking to fine-tune the hyperparameters. This is why I was confused. So given that I assume I can use the entire dataset, right?

Comment: @ToTom - Sorry about the confusion. We are essentially saying the exact same thing. I've alluded below. Hopefully it helps clears things up - if you're still confused, tag Mohammed or myself and I'm sure we will elaborate further. :)