# Do we only use training data when using cross_val_score?

Tags: python, validation, cross-validation

Do we feed the cross_val_score with training data or the whole data? I'm confused when using cross_val_score. I know that we partition our data to training and testing and feed our model with training data.

[image: from sckit learn]

This is the example in sckit-learn documentation, using the whole data.

```py
cross_val_score(model, iris.data, iris.target,scoring=scorer, cv=5)
```

Comment: This post - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52249158/do-i-give-cross-val-score-the-entire-dataset-or-just-the-training-set suggest to separate the test set and training set, even while using cross_val_score.

Answer (score 1):

The cross_val_score is used to estimate model's accuracy in a more robust way than with just the typical train-test split. You should feed all the data inside it, and it will make the necessary train-test splits.

In case you need to crossvalidate hyperparameters, then you should run a nested cross validation, with one outer loop to estimate model's accuracy and one inner loop to get the best parameters that will split the train set of the outer loop in train and validation sets. The procedure should be something like:

```
Outer loop:
    Split train - test
    Inner loop:
       Fix parameters      
       Split train in train2 - validation
       Train with train2 set
       Score with validation set
       Repeat Inner loop for all parameters
   Train with train set and best parameters from inner loop
   Score with test
   Repeat outer loop until CV ends
   Return test scores
```

Fortunately, sklearn allows one to nest a GridSearchCV inside a cross_val_score.

```
validation = GridSearchCV(estimator, param_grid)
score = cross_val_score(validation, X, y)
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass the whole training data and `sklearn` will split it based on the `cv` parameter.

The output will be from the test portion automatically created on each iteration.

Comment: So, inside cross_val_score the sklearn will split our data to train,validation and testing?

Comment: train and test to be accurate, but yes, that's basically how it works

Comment: So there is no validation set? I think we use the cross_val_score to find the best hyper parameter. I'm sorry, I updated the question with picture from sklearn documenntation.

Comment: If you are using it to optimize your hyper-parameters, you can leave a portion of the training set out, use `cross_val_score` until you find the optimal model with the remaining data, and then test your optimal model with the portion of the data that you excluded on the first place.